# How to automatically switch focus to python console when running script in Pycharm?

Tags: python, macos, console, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Hi I am wondering how I can have the python console pop up automatically after I run a script in Pycharm. Currently it opens in the background and I have to either command-tab to it, or click manually. Maybe there is a way to edit the configuration to allow it to pop up, I haven't found one.

Thanks

Comment: Here you will find the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53345342/11073169https://stackoverflow.com/q/53345342/11073169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the same window know so much easier to go to it.