# PyCharm focus Python Console for input upon run

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm 2018.2.5 (Community Edition), I have bound a keyboard shortcut to "Run File in Console". This launches opens the console and runs the file, but does not focus the console for input and anything I type goes into my code. (Sometimes when I use the switcher to focus the Python console it will try to search console variables when I type.)

Is there a way to automatically focus the Python console for input when it is launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut to switch between the code and console is `Alt+4`; by clicking on the console or using this shortcut, future consoles you open will be selected by the input.

Answer (score 3):

No for PyCharm there is no way to automatically focus the Python console for input when it is launched.

In [Notepad ++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) i can do the following.

1. Enter my code
2. press shift+a to execute a macro which saves the file and execute it with Python 2.7 (or 3). I also made this macro a menu item.
3. When the console runs and the script asks for input you are already in focus and can directly put in our entry without having to click and highlight the window or so as it is necessary in PyCharm.

So the step between writing the code and executing it to see what it does exactly one hotkey. Its not one hotkey and a mouse click or what ever no.... its exactly one press of a button. This makes learning very effective because there are no detours.

I looked long in PyCHarm but i could not find this functionality or a workaround. So the answer to your question is "With PyCharm this is not possible."

Here is how to do it in Notepad ++.

- Download Notepad ++
- In N++ install the NppExec Plugin.
- Create the "save and run in python" macro: In NppExec create a script as shown here:

  ```
  NPP_CONSOLE 0 
  npp_save 
  npp_run cmd /K C:\Python27\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
  ```
- Save your macro script as say "Save and run in Python Selfmade"
- In the hotykeys menu assign your macro to a new hotkey.
- In the Npp_Exec menu click on Advanced Options and create a menu entry for your macro. To do this select the script you created under "Associated Script" and then click on "Add/Modify"

Another editor that offers you this quick and direct run functionality is "[Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor))" with its many plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it IS possible

1. in the run console change the view mode to Window (click the cog)
2. add the following lines to the benning of your source code

```
import pygetwindow as gw
win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Run')[0]
win.activate()
```

now it will automatically give focus to the run window... see my youtube demo..  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhmltlUjU3k

Comment: The Working Solution!

Answer (score 1):

I found the option to do this in Run/Debug Configuration.
There is "Modify options" which has "Focus run/debug tool when started"

This is with PyCharm 2023.2.5 (Community Edition) on macOS

Answer (score 0):

i have just posted something related to this. It is needed to distinguish between "Python console" and "python or debug console" within the keymap options. The first one focus at the console but without automatically move caret to it, the later does it.

See more detailes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62118515/5149220) answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy! Just make macros with two actions:

1 - Run command,

2 - Activate run tool window. And with keymap in settings create a shortcut. For example, I do this with `shift + f10` .

Comment: Please explain how could you add the action "activate run tool window" to macros.

Comment: Sorry for the looong answer. If you are still interested, just click on it. Make simple script with only input. Start record. Run it, click run tool window, stop record..

Answer (score 0):

Within the 'Execute NppExec Script :

- Insert the **NPP_CONSOLE 0** command somewhere at the beginning to hide the console.
- Then insert the **NPP_CONSOLE 1** command somewhere before the python command to show the console again. The console will get and keep the focus.

Example :

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
NPP_SAVE
NPP_CONSOLE 1
cd "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
C:/dev/Python/Python3/python.exe -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```